# Linking data to chart using VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, microsoft-excel-2007

I'm trying to connect this data to my chart, but I'm getting application defined or object defined error .

```vb
Dim chtObj As ChartObject
For Each chtObj In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
chtObj.Delete
Next

Dim myChartObject As ChartObject
Set myChartObject = Application.Workbooks(file_name).Worksheets("PP_DETAILS").ChartObjects.Add(Left:=200, Top:=200, Width:=400, Height:=300)

Application.Workbooks(file_name).Worksheets("PP_DETAILS").Range("M2:M7").Select

Application.Workbooks(file_name).Worksheets("PP_DETAILS").ChartObjects.SetSourceData Source:=Range("PP_DETAILS!$M$2:$M$7")
Application.Workbooks(file_name).Worksheets("PP_DETAILS").ChartObjects.ChartType = xlColumnClustered
```

Comment: at which line do you get the error?

Comment: `Worksheets(...).ChartObjects` is a collection, if you want to manage the chart, then use `Worksheets(...).ChartObjects(1)`